# How do you debug an Azure WebJob that won't start?

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a WebJob that is triggered by an Azure Storage Queue. When I test this locally everything works fine. When I publish the WebJob (as part of an Azure WebSite) and then go to the Azure Management Portal and try to start the WebJob, it throws and error.

I had this running earlier, but it was having problems so I deleted the job in the management portal and tried to republish the web site with the web job.

Any suggestions on how to figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the old Azure Management Portal there was no clear way I could find to kill the process (stop the Job if there was one). Using the new portal, I looked at all the processes running on the site and there was the WebJob running 26 threads. After killing the process I was able to start the recent uploaded one.